# Cannot Commit in Cygwin/Git, Windows XP [Unrecognized TERM Type]

Tags: git, cygwin

Same issue when I try to open `vi`. `bash` is the shell I'm using. `vi`, or `git commit`, fails miserably saying "`Unrecognized TERM Type`".

I did some googling. They all suggests setting the TERM type manually like

```
export TERM=vt100
```

Tried and failed. stackoverflow is going to be my last hope. or maybe I should let go of cygwin/git and try something like TortoiseGit.

Any advices will be appreciated.

Comment: the export suggestion is a good one, It was actually what I was going to suggest to you, What is the error you got when exporting the TERM? Also what is it before exporting. By the way the error is not from bash but from vi

Comment: What's the terminal in which you're doing this?  Is it `cmd.exe`? Also, what does `echo $TERMINFO` say?

Comment: In the meantime before you get things working, you could try committing using git commit -m "commit message", in which case you wouldn't need vi and the commit should work.

Comment: @hhafez the initial TERM is cygwin. when I export it, there isn't any error messages.

Comment: @Alok I believe it's cmd.exe. What else does Windows XP get? Oh, BTW, I do have PowerShell installed. But I'm sure it's not the terminal cygwin uses. `echo $TERMINFO` gives nothing.

Comment: @Jani thanks! didn't know that XD 

I was following the official git tutorial. I guess when `git commit` failed I'd lost my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the info, nil. So with `TERM` equal to `cygwin` there is no error?

Comment: sorry, I might misunderstood your question. all of the commands were performed in the `cygwin` window.

When I fire cygwin up, `echo $TERM` gives `cygwin`. `echo $TERMINFO` give nothing.

I've tried different TERM types, none would have `git` or `vi` work properly.

Comment: Do you have more than one `git` installed on your system? What does `which git` report?

Answer (score 3):

Start>Run>cmd

C:\some_path>bash.exe

bash$ vi

Unrecognized TERM Type

bash$ **unset TERM**;vi

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

linux is the new vt100, try

```
export TERM=linux
```

you'll want to make sure that whatever you set TERM to exists in the /usr/share/terminfo subdirectory

Comment: no that didn't work. both TERM type, `vt100` and `linux`, exist in my /usr/share/terminfo directory. 

Thanks for the answer.